# How to get current logged users email address to the value attribute in @Html tag in razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET C# with entity framework to build a website. In here I'm managing a user profile also. So i want to edit my profile details according to the logged user's email address. But email is the primary key and i don't want to give it for editing. I want to keep email text-field as non-editable field and need to visible email of the current logged user in there. So for that i have coded that email part in my `Profile.cshtml` file as follows.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" , **Value = "Session['UserEmail'].ToString()"**})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But the above highlighted part will not give me the email to the text field. Instead of that it will display the `Session['UserEmail'].ToString()` this as it is after rendering. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate the value in your model, don't try and override the value in the view:

### Controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   var myModel = new MyModel() {Email = Session['UserEmail'].ToString();}
   return View(myModel);
}
```

### View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

i.e. don't put `Value = "Session['UserEmail'].ToString()"` above. It won't work. the Model holds the data, the view simply renders this data

Comment: No Problem @Thari